# Edit specific indexes from a feature of Attribute Table QGIS

Tags: indexing

I have an attribute table with many columns. One of them describes a unique code. The column's name is "specialcode" and the column's type is String(254). I want to do the following:

1. Sort every feature with exactly 6 indexes in the "specialcode" column and select them.
2. For every feature from the selection, remove the first 4 indexes, and in the end, only the last 2  indexes (digits) remain as a value for the column "specialcode"

I am assuming it's pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a [field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html) in QGIS. The syntax is following:

```
CASE
WHEN  length(  "specialcode" ) = 6
THEN  right( "specialcode" ,  2)
ELSE Null
END
```

This will replace all other values with Null. If you want to keep them - use `ELSE "specialcode"` instead of `ELSE Null`

Also you have 2 options to store new values - "create a new field" or "update existing field".
[image]